# Angular Flex box won't align in rows?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a section of text, and a button I would like to appear to the right of text.  I use a row based flex box for this purposes, but it isn't working and can't figure out why.  Here's the code and css.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="agrement-viewer">
        <div class="agreement-text" [innerHTML]='text + "<p>Document Hash: " + hash + "</p>"'>
        </div>
        <div class="sign-button">
            <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="signWithMetamaskWallet()">Sign with
                Metmask Wallet</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

scss:

```
.container {
    width: 100%;
   padding: 20px;
}

.agreement-viewer {
    width: 1200px;
    display: flex;   
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: flex-start;
    background-color: blue;
}
.agreement-text {
    width: 800px;
    background-color: pink;
}
 
.sign-button {
    width: 250px;
}
```

No matter how wid the window is, but button remains stubbornly at the bottom beneath the text, as if it was flex-direction: column.  Any suggestions? Perhaps I'm overlooking something simple?  The one observation I have to share is that notwithstanding 'agreement-viewer' is styled with background-color: blue, I see no blue on the rendered page.  Only pink behind the text. (The window is at least 2x wider than the pink part.)  I use Angular Material in this project, but in this component Im not using any Material components except the button.
Thoughts or suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in your code:

#### HTML

```
 <div class="agrement-viewer">
```

#### SCSS

```
.agreement-viewer {
    width: 1200px;
    display: flex;   
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: flex-start;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

You miss an **e** in agre**e**ment-viewer html.

Comment: Thanks.  Funny how you can look at piece of code 300 times and keep missing the typo.